# Add Custom theme to react-codemirror2?

Tags: themes, codemirror, react-codemirror2

I dropped the theme into the react-codemirror2 folder inside the node modules folder, but the theme could not be found when building, because when I copy the new packages, the file disappears.

How to create a custom theme?

Answer (score 0):

Hello  [Abbos Rakhmono](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13094666/abbos-rakhmonov),

react-codemirror2 has quite a useful number of theme options to use that must surely be similar to what you want.

You can find an example in the demo [here](https://codemirror.net/5/demo/theme.html#3024-day)

---

Here is also an example of me using the **"material"** theme in the **options** prop.

***Note:** You have to also import the specific CSS stylesheet for each theme you wish to use to enable proper linting*

import 'codemirror/theme/material.css'

```
  import 'codemirror/theme/material.css'


  <ControlledEditor
    onBeforeChange={handleChange}
    value={value}
    className="code-mirror-wrapper"
    options={{
      lineWrapping: true,
      lint: true,
      mode: xml,
      lineNumbers: true,
      theme: 'material'
      
    }}
  />
```

Hope this helps. You can reply to this post if you need further assistance.